# Opencart registration does not registers the user after removing required fields (no error is returned)

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm using Opencart 2.
I have followed the following guide to remove required fields from the registration page: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=46467

After removing the required fields from `regiser.tpl` I was getting some validation errors but I solved those errors by following the steps below:

1. Go to `controller->account` directory, then
2. open `register.php`, then
3. go to function `validate`, then
4. change validation according to your requirement.

Now that I've resolved all validation errors, the user is not being saved. It seems like the page is only reloading when I submit the registration form.

I'm posting this question so that if someone has been through this weird behavior of opencart before he can help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Opencart. 
But logically speaking for sure it wont register anything as the DB will try to get some variables that are needed for the query. And it won't find any as you already removed those!

Same link you provided another user gave the answer as well.

> Don't remove the input fields, change their type from "text" to "hidden". Removing them will only cause errors, as no field is passed through to the db query in the model.

So Please try to follow his/her suggestion!

Comment: in the `register.php` controller I'm assigning a default value of `''` if a field doesn't exist

Comment: all the fields in the db are VARCHAR can anyone of those be INT? and instead of  ' ' it will set a 0 to the INT fields! maybe they are somewhere requested not to be 0! by the way did you make a backup of the register.php and try to follow the method hidden?

Comment: It's ok, I resolved the problem. The problem was with the `zone field` that I forgot to remove validate from because it was not generating any error. After removing validation on that field the user was created successfully. Thanks for your contribution I will give you an up vote for your time spent on this.